# What is uint256?

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, integers

With regard to Solidity, What is UINT256?

From the token example at https://ethereum.org/token :

```
/* This creates an array with all balances */
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
```

Beyond being a variable type in general computing, I'd love to gain a better of understanding and context in the Ethereum world.  Why not just use an INT?  Assuming it's a specific type of Integer, what does the "U" denote?

Comment: It is an integer type https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#integers

Comment: I found, uint means unsigned int.  uint doesn't allow for negative numbers, it has a range of 0 to 4,294,967,295, compared to the range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 for an int (Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068474/difference-of-using-int-and-uint-and-when-to-use)

Comment: @BruceSeymour Those are default C# types - I'm pretty sure C# has a default int length that's way shorter than Solidity's default, thus different ranges.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> With regard to Solidity...

This is really more a general computer science question that would best be answered on Stack Overflow.

At the risk of repeating what @Ismael has linked to...

- `U` - [unsigned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signedness) (meaning this type can only represent positive integers, *not* positive **and** negative integers)
- `INT` - integer
- `256` - 256 bits in size

**Context:** The EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine) uses 256 bits as its word size. See: [Rationale behind 256-bit words in EVM](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7382/rationale-behind-256-bit-words-in-evm)

Comment: Thanks, the context with regard to solidity is helpful. I also found this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247873/signed-versus-unsigned-integers

Comment: it's better to give an example of what a uint256 looks like.

Answer (score 18):

Integers in Solidity:

`uint256` (`uint` is an alias) is a unsigned integer which has:

- minimum value of 0
- maximum value of 2^256-1 = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935 //78 decimal digits

`int256` (`int` is an alias) is a signed integer which has:

- minimum value of -2^255 = -57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968
- maximum value of 2^255-1 = 57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819967

For example, in Solidity we could write the following code:

```
uint8 public constant decimals = 6;
uint256 public constant totalSupply = 1000000*10**uint256(decimals); // 1000000000000
```

P.S. It is unusual that `int`/`uint` in Solidity have 256 bits in size, because there are such popular languages as C#/Java that have `int` data type with 32 bits in size:

- minimum value of -2^31 = -2147483648
- maximum value of 2^31-1 = 2147483647

Comment: I think 256 bits was chosen so that there would be enough addresses for the ethereum network to continue to work indefinitely.

Comment: @forgetso addresses in Ethereum are 160 bits, not 256 bits. Words in the EVM are 256 bits in length, and `uint256` is almost always used for balances.